# Using Ionic3 code with Ionic4 version installed - without migrating

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I have not yet migrated my **Ionic3** app to **Ionic4**, and continued using the last Ionic3 version that I had installed (3.20) before Ionic4 came out. I assumed that in order to use Ionic4, the code itself would have to be compatible with all the changes that came with Ionic4 - the new project structure/folders, installing Angular 6 and up, changing component and function names and so on. 
After recently installing the latest Ionic4 version by accident via `npm install -g ionic`, I did a clean `npm install` on the Ionic3 project without changing anything in the **package.json**, and after `ionic serve` the Ionic3 app seems to run without any problems.
I did not see anything official from Ionic regarding this issue or backwards compatibility support - Is it OK to continue with Ionic3 code and an Ionic4 version installed? Or is there some other reason?

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.3",
    "angularfire2": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "4.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

And the Ionic version

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you run `ionic info`, you'll see your current CLI version and your current framework version within the project. So your global Ionic CLI can be 4.12.0 and you can still run ionic 3 in your project just fine as long as the framework if 3~.

Ionic Info:

[image]